# What's the most elegant method to transform models between pytorch and caffe?

Tags: caffe, pytorch, pycaffe

Just like title says, models pytorch to caffe, caffe to pytorch.

Not only inference, but also trainable models after transformation.

Any good points?

Comment: try [onnx](https://onnx.ai/)

Comment: @Shai I only saw caffe2 on onnx website, is that compatible with caffe?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to check it out